# Reading R DataFrame in C#

Tags: c#, r

I have a R script that uses rCLR to call a function in C#. The R Script reads a CSV file and stores it in data frame. I want to pass this data frame to C# function. The question is what signature do I use for the C# function. I used something like ReadDataFrame(object[] dataframe) { } and I can see that dataframe variable in C# is populated like an array but all elements are null. Any idea how this can be achieved? By the way if I pass string from R script to C# that works if my C# function accepts string. Just the data frame I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Prasad

Comment: I think you need a two dimensional array.   Either object[][] or object[,]

Comment: No that wont work (I tried that). R passes an object not object as single dimensional not 2D. This is what you get if you change C# method signature to [,] -  Type:    System.MissingMethodException
Message: Could not find a suitable instance method LoadUserDataHistory on type IAM.HelperMethods for method parameters Object[]